# Howto pass Java system properties to maven-cargo container

Tags: java, testing, maven-2, continuous-integration, maven-cargo

I'm preparing a maven2 web project for continuous integration. I use the [maven cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) to automatically deploy the WAR to Tomcat6x before running integration tests.

My code depends on some system properties which are set with `MAVEN_OPTS=-Dfoo=bar`. Unfortunately these properties are missing when the application is deployed to Tomcat:

```
System.getProperty("foo"); // null, when deployed to container by maven-cargo
```

How can I pass these properties to Tomcat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do this by using the systemProperties tag in the container definition of the plugin:

```
      <container>
        [...]
      <systemProperties>
        <MAVEN_OPTS>-Dfoo=bar</MAVEN_OPTS>
      </systemProperties>
    </container>
```

Or you can set this in a setenv.sh (on linux) file in your $CATALINA_HOME/bin/ directory. If this file does not exist you should create it and add the following line:

```
MAVEN_OPTS=-Dfoo=bar
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I tried using <systemProperties> but I must have made something wrong. To set "foo=bar" the XML looks like:

      <container>
        [...]
      <systemProperties>
        <foo>bar</bar>
      </systemProperties>
    </container>

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this by using the systemProperties tag in the container definition of the plugin:

```
<container>
  <systemProperties>
    <foo>bar</foo>
  </systemProperties>
</container>
```

this is equivalent to pass -Dfoo=bar in command line or in another option.